# Is there a way to split an array of strings into subarray of strings on token

Tags: c, arrays, string, split

Basically, is there any way to split an array of strings into arrays of strings before and after a token (`"|"`) in C.

An example is shown below.

```
char *input[] = {"hello","I","am","|","a","cool","|","guy"}

//code
```

and the result is 3 arrays, containing

```
{"Hello","I","am"}
{"a","cool"}
{"guy"}
```

I tried `strtok` but that seems to split a string into pieces, rather than an array of strings into new, separate, sub-arrays of strings. I also do not know exactly how many `"|"` tokens will be present, and will need an unknown amount of new arrays (safe to say it'd be less than 10). They will be passed to `execvp` so having it as one string and just remembering where to start and stop looking will not work.

Comment: can you be more specific on your problem? is that finding "|" is that having unknown size arrays or is that using exevp in the end?

Comment: for finding the `|`, `strtok` is useless as it is in a separate string. You can just iterate thru the array and look for the strings that are `"|"`

Comment: sorry, so I'm having an issue making the sub arrays. I have an array of locations of the | token in my main array of strings, I just don't know how to make multiple, separate arrays that contain each segment. I tried having a pointer the string after each "|" character and then replacing each | with "\0" but that also didn't work

Comment: just post your code so we can see where you are and what can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need manually to split the input array. And dynamically allocate a new place to store result. E.g. as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    char *input[] = {"hello","I","am","|","a","cool","|","guy"};

    int inputLength = sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]);
    printf("inputLength - %d\n", inputLength);
    const char ***result2DimArray = malloc(sizeof(char**) * inputLength);
    int *result2DimArrayLengths = malloc(sizeof(int) * inputLength);
    memset(result2DimArrayLengths, 0, sizeof(int) * inputLength);

    const char **currentSection = 0;
    int nextSectionNumber = 0;
    for(int inputIndex = 0; inputIndex < inputLength; inputIndex++)
    {
        if(input[inputIndex][0] == '|')
        {
            currentSection = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(!currentSection)
            {
                currentSection = malloc(sizeof(char*) * inputLength);
                result2DimArray[nextSectionNumber] = currentSection;
                nextSectionNumber++;
            }

            *currentSection = input[inputIndex];
            currentSection++;
            result2DimArrayLengths[nextSectionNumber-1]++;
        }
    }

    /*Checking the result*/
    printf("total sections - %d\n", nextSectionNumber);
    for(int i=0; i<nextSectionNumber;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<result2DimArrayLengths[i];j++)
        {
            printf(result2DimArray[i][j]);
            printf(", ");
        }
        puts("");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To print a `size_t` POSIX mandates the `z` length modifier. As a `size_t` is unsigned the `u` conversion specifier has to be used. Using `d` invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Not really. It should be `"zu"`.

Comment: Dang )). Fixed one more time, I'll just go with `int`, as I'm comparing that variable with `int` anyway

Answer (score 1):

> *They will be passed to execvp*

Assuming the strings include the program to be executed (the 1st parameter to `execvp()`) and the strings will be used in the order of appearance as per this pointer-array

> ```
> char *input[] = {"hello","I","am","|","a","cool","|","guy"}
> ```

then a possible simple solution without any duplications might look like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char * input[] = {"hello", "I", "am", "|", 
                  "a", "cool", "|",
                  "guy", "|"}; /* note the additional trailing `"|"`. */

int main(void)
{
  char ** pcurrent = input;
  char ** pend = pcurrent + sizeof input / sizeof *input;

  while (pcurrent < pend)
  {
    {
      char ** ptmp = pcurrent;
      while (ptmp < pend && **ptmp != '|')
      {
        ++ptmp;
      }

      *ptmp = NULL;
    }

    {
      pid_t pid = fork();
      if ((pid_t) -1) == pid)
      {
        perror("fork() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      if ((pid_t) 0) == pid) /* child */
      {
        execvp(pcurrent[0], pcurrent);
        perror("execvp() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      /* parent */
      pcurrent = ptmp + 1;
    }
  }  /* while (pcurrent < pend) */
}  /* int main(void) */
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which doesn't involve dynamic memory allocation.

Before going in to the details ...

I think it's useful when tackling a problem like this to think about how the "strings" are stored in memory. It might look something like in the attached picture. (The memory addresses are completely unrealistic - and there would be null terminators at the end of each string - but you get the idea).

[image]

As the picture shows, the vital information we need for each 'sub-array' can be stored in a `<char **, int>` pair. The `char **` is the address of the first "string" in the sub-array; the `int` is the number of strings it contains.

We can use a `struct string_array_t` to store this information.

```c
typedef struct {
    // Pointer to first string in sub-array
    char **p;
    // Number of strings in sub-array
    int count;
} string_array_t;
```

We allocate an array of these *on the stack*; thus no need for `malloc()` or `free()` - as long as we allocate enough sub-arrays.

```c
    string_array_t string_arrays[MAX_SUB_ARRAYS] = {0};
    char *input[] = {"hello", "I", "am", "|", "a", "cool", "|", "guy"};
    // Pointer to current sub-array
    string_array_t *cur = NULL;
    size_t n_sub_arrays = 1;
```

Initialize our counters and pointers:

```c
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    cur = &string_arrays[0];
    size_t n_strings_total = sizeof(input) / sizeof(input[0]);
```

Then loop over the array.

```c
    for (i = 0; i < n_strings_total; i++) {
        if (!strcmp(input[i], "|")) {
            // Store total number of strings in this sub-array
            cur->count = k;
            k = 0;
            // Switch to next sub-array
            cur = &string_arrays[++j];
            if (j >= MAX_SUB_ARRAYS) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Not enough sub-arrays allocated ...\n");
                break;
            }
            n_sub_arrays++;
            continue;
        }
        if (k == 0) {
            cur->p = &input[i];
        }
        k++;
    }
    cur->count = k;
```

Print the results.

```c
    printf("Found %zu sub arrays ...\n", n_sub_arrays);
    for (i = 0; i < n_sub_arrays; i++) {
        string_array_t *cur = &string_arrays[i];
        for (j = 0; j < cur->count; j++) {
            printf("%s ", *(cur->p++));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: You can also simply check if the first char is `'|'` and avoid the call to `strcmp`, e.g. `if (*input[i] == '|')` then switch to next sub-array. (through your approach is fine). Also since he mentions using `execvp` the last pointer in each sub-array must be set `NULL` which you can do at the same location within your loop.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I chose `strcmp()` in case there could be strings such as `"|abc"` in the array. It is not clear if the author wishes to consider these as delimiters or not.

Comment: That's why I was clear to point out what you are doing is fine there. The array of struct is a good idea to avoid becoming a Three-star programmer. There is also no guarantee where (or how many of) the `"|"` there will be sprinkled in there, but you do know there will be less than `n_strings_total` pointers required. (and you can use the `sizeof x / sizeof *x` as a compile-time constant if you wanted to avoid allocating for `p` if the number is reasonable)

Comment: `size_t` is unsigned, so to print it use `zu`.